# The meaning of "to derive unto"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "derives unto" in this sentence by James Shirley:"thou canst not see What blemish she derives unto our name"?

Answer (score 2):

**derive unto** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50613?rskey=CcaUcB&result=1&isAdvanced=true#eid6974932)
†4. transf. and fig.

Categories » a. To convey from one (treated as a source) to another, as by transmission, descent, etc.; to transmit, impart, communicate, pass on, hand on. Const. to, into, **unto**, rarely upon the recipient. ** unto** or arch. **(rare after 1750)**.

As in:

> a1661   T. Fuller Worthies (1662) Bucks. 136   Parents..rich enough **to
>   derive unto** him the hereditary infirmity of the gout.

Shirley's use, in the early 17th century was not atypical of English writers, but the use of **to derive unto** is registered as archaic.

Answer (score 0):

**derive** is defined by [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/derive) as:

> derive something from
>
> 1. Obtain something from (a specified source)
>
>    > ‘they derived great comfort from this assurance’

Reading into the meaning of the sentence, what the author is trying to say is that a *blemish* is derived or obtained from *something* unknown and applied *unto* "our name".

Comment: Yes. To paraphrase the original quotation: "You have no idea how seriously she is damaging our reputation."